# Issue with implementing Rabin-Karp algorithm to search string in LeetCode 28 "implement strStr()" using C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I implemented this algorithm to solve Leetcode's #28 question "**implemment strStr()**".
Problem description:
*Implement strStr(), 
Returns the index of the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or -1 if needle is not part of haystack.*

My code was implemented based on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-3-rabin-karp-algorithm/ 's tutoril.

I found out that with different prime number I use to scale down the hash, the function could go wrong.
Here is my code:

```
    public class Solution {
    public int StrStr(string haystack, string needle) {
        int len = needle.Length;
        //2 special case
        if (haystack.Length < len) return -1;
        if (needle == "") return 0;

        //base prime number used for rabin-karp's hash function
        int basement = 101;
        //prime number used to scale down the hash value
        int prime = 101;
        //the factor used to multiply with the character to be removed from the hash
        int factor = (int)(Math.Pow(basement, needle.Length - 1)) % prime;

        //get ascii value of the needle and the initial window
        int needleHash = 0;
        int windowHash = 0;
        byte[] needleBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(needle);
        byte[] windowBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(haystack.Substring(0, len));

        //generate hash value for both
        for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length; i++)
        {
            needleHash = (needleHash * basement + needleBytes[i]) % prime;
            windowHash = (windowHash * basement + windowBytes[i]) % prime;
        }

        //loop to find match
        bool findMatch = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < haystack.Length - len + 1; i++){
            //if hash value matches, incase the hash value are not uniq, iterate through needle and window
            if(needleHash == windowHash){
                findMatch = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                {
                    if (needle[j] != haystack[i + j])
                    {
                        findMatch = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (findMatch == true) return i;
            }
            //move the sliding window and find the hash value for new window
            if (i < haystack.Length - len){
                byte removeByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(haystack.Substring(i, 1))[0];
                byte addByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(haystack.Substring(i + len, 1))[0];
                //function of rolling hash
                windowHash = ((windowHash - removeByte * factor) * basement + addByte) % prime;
                //ensure the window hash to be positive
                if(windowHash < 0) windowHash += prime;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

With "prime" set to "101", this code passes all test. But if i change it to other prime number no matter smaller or larger (example: 17, 31, 103), it always failed at test "68/72" which

haystack = "baabbaaaaaaabbaaaaabbabbababaabbabbbbbab
babbbbbbabababaabbbbbaaabbbbabaababababbbaabbbbaaabbaaba
bbbaabaabbabbaaaabababaaabbabbababbabbaaabbbbabbbbabbabbaabbbaa";
needle = "bbaaaababa";

Thus I do believe my code have big issues that I could not detect. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Two issues with your code:

1. `basement` should be set at 256 per the algorithm at the site you used as a reference. This value is the number of characters in the input alphabet.
2. Your computation of `factor` is not correct; you're casting to `int` before calculating the remainder. The `Math.Pow` operation results in a `double` value that is larger than `Int32.MaxValue`. When you cast to int *before* the modulo operation you truncate this value. You need to perform the modulo with the `double` value and *then* cast to `int`. The line should look like this:

   int factor = (int)((Math.Pow(basement, needle.Length - 1)) % prime);

I tested your code with these modifications and the example given and it works for primes of 17, 31, 101 and 103.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Modify the code in your way does pass all test :D. But I'd like to have some further discuss, For the 1st issue, refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), the `basement` is a big prime number. But in the site I referred it used `256` which is the ascii size. I got confused about the basement choice. For the 2nd issue, I don't see the difference between casting before or after the modulo calculation,can you explain the difference?